# Convert json objects to array of objects using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have following JSON

```
{
        "ID": "123",
        "Name": "xyz"
}
{
        "ID": "1234",
        "Competitor": "abc"
}
```

Need to convert the json objects into a array of json objects:

```
[
{
        "ID": "123",
        "Name": "xyz"
}
{
        "ID": "1234",
        "Competitor": "abc"
}
]
```

I have tried using:

```
. | [{ID, Name}]
```

But this converts into multiple arrays

```
[
{
        "ID": "123",
        "Name": "xyz"
}
]
[
{
        "ID": "1234",
        "Competitor": "abc"
}
]
```

Comment: Have a look at the `--slurp` (or `-s`) option when [invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jq applies the given filter to each JSON document/entity. A file can contain multiple such documents. If you want to handle a file with multiple documents as a single array document with each original document being an array element, then use `-s`/`--slurp` option which will read all JSON documents in your input file as one huge array:

```
jq -s '.' input.json
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "ID": "123",
    "Name": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "ID": "1234",
    "Competitor": "abc"
  }
]
```

Note that jq *requires* valid JSON, so your input *must* be valid. The sample in the question is not. A valid JSON input would be:

```json
{
        "ID": "123",
        "Name": "xyz"
}
{
        "ID": "1234",
        "Competitor": "abc"
}
```

PS Note that `. | [{ID, Name}]` is equivalent to `[{ID, Name}]` since `.` is the identity filter.